# Where to find documentation about the kernel device tree pinctrl parameters?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-device-driver, stm32

I'm trying to add a new ethernet device to an existing stm32mp1 board, but I'm a bit lost in the device tree section.

What I found so far:

In the *board.dts* file, i could find the pins which connects to the ethernet PHY:

```dts
&pinctrl {
    ethernet0_rgmii_pins: rgmii-0 {
        pins1 {
            pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('G', 4, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_GTX_CLK */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('B', 12, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_TXD0 */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('G', 14, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_TXD1 */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('C', 2, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_TXD2 */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('E', 2, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_TXD3 */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('G', 11, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_TX_CTL */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('C', 1, AF11)>; /* ETH_MDC */
            bias-disable;
            drive-push-pull;
            slew-rate = <2>;
        };

        pins2 {
            pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('A', 2, AF11)>; /* ETH_MDIO */
            bias-disable;
            drive-push-pull;
            slew-rate = <0>;
        };

        pins3 {
            pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('C', 4, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_RXD0 */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('C', 5, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_RXD1 */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('H', 6, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_RXD2 */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('H', 7, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_RXD3 */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('A', 1, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_RX_CLK */
                     <STM32_PINMUX('A', 7, AF11)>; /* ETH_RGMII_RX_CTL */
            bias-disable;
        };
    };
};

&ethernet0 {
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-0 = <&ethernet0_rmii_pins>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    phy-mode = "rgmii";
    phy-handle = <&phy0>;
    st,eth_clk_sel = <1>;
    max-speed = <1000>;
    clock-names = "stmmaceth", "mac-clk-tx", "mac-clk-rx", "eth-ck", "syscfg-clk", "ethstp";
    clocks = <&rcc ETHMAC>, <&rcc ETHTX>, <&rcc ETHRX>, <&rcc ETHCK_K>, <&rcc SYSCFG>, <&rcc ETHSTP>;

    mdio0 {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        compatible = "snps,dwmac-mdio";
        phy0: ethernet-phy@0 {
            reg = <0>;
            ti,rx-internal-delay = <DP83867_RGMIIDCTL_2_25_NS>;
            ti,tx-internal-delay = <DP83867_RGMIIDCTL_2_75_NS>;
            ti,fifo-depth = <DP83867_PHYCR_FIFO_DEPTH_4_B_NIB>;
            ti,dp83867-rxctrl-strap-quirk;
        };
    };
};
```

For example in the pins1 section the following pins are connected:

```dts
pinmux = <STM32_PINMUX('G', 4, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_GTX_CLK */
         <STM32_PINMUX('B', 12, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_TXD0 */
         <STM32_PINMUX('G', 14, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_TXD1 */
         <STM32_PINMUX('C', 2, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_TXD2 */
         <STM32_PINMUX('E', 2, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_TXD3 */
         <STM32_PINMUX('G', 11, AF11)>, /* ETH_RGMII_TX_CTL */
         <STM32_PINMUX('C', 1, AF11)>; /* ETH_MDC */
```

And then the pin-group is later used here:

```dts
pinctrl-0 = <&ethernet0_rgmii_pins>;
pinctrl-names = "default";
```

But how and where is the order defined? How is it passed later to the PHY device driver? What if i change the PHY from RGMII to RMII? Then the number of pins reduce, but in what order do I have to place the pins?

Sadly I just can't find any documentation to it, maybe someone can help me out here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Order does not matter. All what pinctrl does is connecting physical pins into right peripheral. Piece of silicon acting as GMAC peripheral does not care which particular pin is using.

I doubt is possible to swap roles of pins B12 and G14 to act as TXD1 and TXD0 if this is what you are concerned about.